# Dreamweaver CS6 color scheme differs from other Creative Suite apps

Tags: dreamweaver, adobe-creative-suite

I'm wondering if there is a dark color scheme I can enable in Dreamweaver CS6 like the new PS & Ai UIs.  I didn't find an option anywhere and was hoping there's a mod for this.  Are all versions the same in reference to interface design? I have the student/teacher ed btw.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not.

If you would like this feature, the best approach would be to [submit a feature request.](http://blogs.adobe.com/dreamweaver/2009/04/making_feature_requests.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to http://www.adobe.com/accessibility/products/dreamweaver/overview.html if you set your Windows theme to High Contrast Black, then Dreamweaver CS6's interface will also turn black.